# How to connect from a public GKE pod to a GCP Cloud SQL using a private connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have a Java application running in a docker container. I am deploying all this to my GKE cluster. I'd like to have it connected to a CloudSQL instance via private IP. However I struggle for two days now to get it working. I followed the following guide:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-services-access#gcloud_1

I managed to create a private service connection and also gave my CloudSQL instance the address range. As far as I understood this should be sufficient for the Pod to be able to connect to the CloudSQL instance.

However it just does not work. I pass the private IP from CloudSQL as the host for the Java application JDBC (Database) connection.

```
│ 2022-02-14 22:03:31.299  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata                                                │
│                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│ com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

---

Here are some details to the problem.

The address allocation

```sh
➜  google-cloud-sdk gcloud compute addresses list
NAME                             ADDRESS/RANGE  TYPE      PURPOSE      NETWORK  REGION  SUBNET  STATUS
google-managed-services-default  10.77.0.0/16   INTERNAL  VPC_PEERING  default                  RESERVED
```

The vpc peering connection

```sh
➜  google-cloud-sdk gcloud services vpc-peerings list --network=default                  
---
network: projects/1071923183712/global/networks/default
peering: servicenetworking-googleapis-com
reservedPeeringRanges:
- google-managed-services-default
service: services/servicenetworking.googleapis.com
```

Here is my CloudSQL info. Please not that the PRIVATE IP Address is `10.77.0.5` and therefore matches the address range from above `10.77.0.0/16`. I guess this part is working.

```yaml
➜  google-cloud-sdk gcloud sql instances describe alpha-3 
backendType: SECOND_GEN
connectionName: barbarus:europe-west4:alpha-3
createTime: '2022-02-14T19:28:02.465Z'
databaseInstalledVersion: MYSQL_5_7_36
databaseVersion: MYSQL_5_7
etag: 758de240b161b946689e5732d8e71d396c772c0e03904c46af3b61f59b1038a0
gceZone: europe-west4-a
instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
ipAddresses:
- ipAddress: 34.90.174.243
  type: PRIMARY
- ipAddress: 10.77.0.5
  type: PRIVATE
kind: sql#instance
name: alpha-3
project: barbarus
region: europe-west4
selfLink: https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/barbarus/instances/alpha-3
serverCaCert:
  cert: |-
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    //...
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
  certSerialNumber: '0'
  commonName: C=US,O=Google\, Inc,CN=Google Cloud SQL Server CA,dnQualifier=d495898b-f6c7-4e2f-9c59-c02ccf2c1395
  createTime: '2022-02-14T19:29:35.325Z'
  expirationTime: '2032-02-12T19:30:35.325Z'
  instance: alpha-3
  kind: sql#sslCert
  sha1Fingerprint: 3ee799b139bf335ef39554b07a5027c9319087cb
serviceAccountEmailAddress: p1071923183712-d99fsz@gcp-sa-cloud-sql.iam.gserviceaccount.com
settings:
  activationPolicy: ALWAYS
  availabilityType: ZONAL
  backupConfiguration:
    backupRetentionSettings:
      retainedBackups: 7
      retentionUnit: COUNT
    binaryLogEnabled: true
    enabled: true
    kind: sql#backupConfiguration
    location: us
    startTime: 12:00
    transactionLogRetentionDays: 7
  dataDiskSizeGb: '10'
  dataDiskType: PD_HDD
  ipConfiguration:
    allocatedIpRange: google-managed-services-default
    ipv4Enabled: true
    privateNetwork: projects/barbarus/global/networks/default
    requireSsl: false
  kind: sql#settings
  locationPreference:
    kind: sql#locationPreference
    zone: europe-west4-a
  pricingPlan: PER_USE
  replicationType: SYNCHRONOUS
  settingsVersion: '1'
  storageAutoResize: true
  storageAutoResizeLimit: '0'
  tier: db-f1-micro
state: RUNNABLE
```

The problem I see is with the Pod's IP Address. It is `10.0.5.3` and that is not in the range of `10.77.0.0/16` and therefore the pod can't see the CloudSQL instance.

See here is the Pod's info:

```yaml
Name:         game-server-5b9dd47cbd-vt2gw
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         gke-barbarus-node-pool-1a5ea7d5-bg3m/10.164.15.216
Start Time:   Tue, 15 Feb 2022 00:33:56 +0100
Labels:       app=game-server
              app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=gcp-cloud-build-deploy
              pod-template-hash=5b9dd47cbd
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.0.5.3
IPs:
  IP:           10.0.5.3
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/game-server-5b9dd47cbd
Containers:
  game-server:
    Container ID:   containerd://57d9540b1e5f5cb3fcc4517fa42377282943d292ba810c83cd7eb50bd4f1e3dd
    Image:          eu.gcr.io/barbarus/game-server@sha256:72d518a53652d32d0d438d2a5443c44cc8e12bb15cb1a59c843ce72466900141
    Image ID:       eu.gcr.io/barbarus/game-server@sha256:72d518a53652d32d0d438d2a5443c44cc8e12bb15cb1a59c843ce72466900141
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 15 Feb 2022 00:36:48 +0100
      Finished:     Tue, 15 Feb 2022 00:38:01 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 15 Feb 2022 00:35:23 +0100
      Finished:     Tue, 15 Feb 2022 00:36:35 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  2
    Environment:
      SQL_CONNECTION:  <set to the key 'SQL_CONNECTION' of config map 'game-server'>  Optional: false
      SQL_USER:        <set to the key 'SQL_USER' of config map 'game-server'>        Optional: false
      SQL_DATABASE:    <set to the key 'SQL_DATABASE' of config map 'game-server'>    Optional: false
      SQL_PASSWORD:    <set to the key 'SQL_PASSWORD' of config map 'game-server'>    Optional: false
      LOG_LEVEL:       <set to the key 'LOG_LEVEL' of config map 'game-server'>       Optional: false
      WORLD_ID:        <set to the key 'WORLD_ID' of config map 'game-server'>        Optional: false
      WORLD_SIZE:      <set to the key 'WORLD_SIZE' of config map 'game-server'>      Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-sknlk (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-sknlk:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  4m7s                 default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/game-server-5b9dd47cbd-vt2gw to gke-barbarus-node-pool-1a5ea7d5-bg3m
  Normal   Pulling    4m6s                 kubelet            Pulling image "eu.gcr.io/barbarus/game-server@sha256:72d518a53652d32d0d438d2a5443c44cc8e12bb15cb1a59c843ce72466900141"
  Normal   Pulled     3m55s                kubelet            Successfully pulled image "eu.gcr.io/barbarus/game-server@sha256:72d518a53652d32d0d438d2a5443c44cc8e12bb15cb1a59c843ce72466900141" in 11.09487284s
  Normal   Created    75s (x3 over 3m54s)  kubelet            Created container game-server
  Normal   Started    75s (x3 over 3m54s)  kubelet            Started container game-server
  Normal   Pulled     75s (x2 over 2m41s)  kubelet            Container image "eu.gcr.io/barbarus/game-server@sha256:72d518a53652d32d0d438d2a5443c44cc8e12bb15cb1a59c843ce72466900141" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    1s (x2 over 87s)     kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Finally this is what `gcloud container clusters describe` gives me:

```yaml
➜  google-cloud-sdk gcloud container clusters describe --region=europe-west4 barbarus
addonsConfig:
  gcePersistentDiskCsiDriverConfig:
    enabled: true
  kubernetesDashboard:
    disabled: true
  networkPolicyConfig:
    disabled: true
autopilot: {}
autoscaling:
  autoscalingProfile: BALANCED
binaryAuthorization: {}
clusterIpv4Cidr: 10.0.0.0/14
createTime: '2022-02-14T19:34:03+00:00'
currentMasterVersion: 1.21.6-gke.1500
currentNodeCount: 3
currentNodeVersion: 1.21.6-gke.1500
databaseEncryption:
  state: DECRYPTED
endpoint: 34.141.141.150
id: 39e7249b48c24d23a8b70b0c11cd18901565336b397147dab4778dc75dfc34e2
initialClusterVersion: 1.21.6-gke.1500
initialNodeCount: 1
instanceGroupUrls:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/barbarus/zones/europe-west4-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-barbarus-node-pool-e291e3d6-grp
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/barbarus/zones/europe-west4-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-barbarus-node-pool-5aa35c39-grp
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/barbarus/zones/europe-west4-c/instanceGroupManagers/gke-barbarus-node-pool-380645b7-grp
ipAllocationPolicy:
  useRoutes: true
labelFingerprint: a9dc16a7
legacyAbac: {}
location: europe-west4
locations:
- europe-west4-a
- europe-west4-b
- europe-west4-c
loggingConfig:
  componentConfig:
    enableComponents:
    - SYSTEM_COMPONENTS
    - WORKLOADS
loggingService: logging.googleapis.com/kubernetes
maintenancePolicy:
  resourceVersion: e3b0c442
masterAuth:
  clusterCaCertificate: // ...
masterAuthorizedNetworksConfig: {}
monitoringConfig:
  componentConfig:
    enableComponents:
    - SYSTEM_COMPONENTS
monitoringService: monitoring.googleapis.com/kubernetes
name: barbarus
network: default
networkConfig:
  defaultSnatStatus: {}
  network: projects/barbarus/global/networks/default
  serviceExternalIpsConfig: {}
  subnetwork: projects/barbarus/regions/europe-west4/subnetworks/default
nodeConfig:
  diskSizeGb: 100
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS_CONTAINERD
  machineType: e2-medium
  metadata:
    disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
  preemptible: true
  serviceAccount: default@barbarus.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  shieldedInstanceConfig:
    enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
nodeIpv4CidrSize: 24
nodePoolDefaults:
  nodeConfigDefaults: {}
nodePools:
- config:
    diskSizeGb: 100
    diskType: pd-standard
    imageType: COS_CONTAINERD
    machineType: e2-medium
    metadata:
      disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
    oauthScopes:
    - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
    preemptible: true
    serviceAccount: default@barbarus.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    shieldedInstanceConfig:
      enableIntegrityMonitoring: true
  initialNodeCount: 1
  instanceGroupUrls:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/barbarus/zones/europe-west4-a/instanceGroupManagers/gke-barbarus-node-pool-e291e3d6-grp
  - https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/barbarus/zones/europe-west4-b/instanceGroupManagers/gke-barbarus-node-pool-5aa35c39-grp
  - https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/barbarus/zones/europe-west4-c/instanceGroupManagers/gke-barbarus-node-pool-380645b7-grp
  locations:
  - europe-west4-a
  - europe-west4-b
  - europe-west4-c
  management:
    autoRepair: true
    autoUpgrade: true
  name: node-pool
  podIpv4CidrSize: 24
  selfLink: https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/barbarus/locations/europe-west4/clusters/barbarus/nodePools/node-pool
  status: RUNNING
  upgradeSettings:
    maxSurge: 1
  version: 1.21.6-gke.1500
notificationConfig:
  pubsub: {}
releaseChannel:
  channel: REGULAR
selfLink: https://container.googleapis.com/v1/projects/barbarus/locations/europe-west4/clusters/barbarus
servicesIpv4Cidr: 10.3.240.0/20
shieldedNodes:
  enabled: true
status: RUNNING
subnetwork: default
zone: europe-west4
```

I have no idea how I can give the pod a reference to the address allocation I made for the private service connection.

What I tried is to spin up a GKE cluster with a Cluster default pod address range of `10.77.0.0/16` which sounded logical since I want the pods to appear in the same address range as the CloudSQL. However GCP gives me an error when I try to do that:

```
(1) insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "CPUS": request requires '9.0' and is short '1.0'. project has a quota of '8.0' with '8.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=hait-barbarus (2) insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES": request requires '9.0' and is short '5.0'. project has a quota of '4.0' with '4.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=hait-barbarus.
```

So I am not able to give the pods the proper address range for the private service connection how can they ever discover the CloudSQL instance?

**EDIT #1**: The GKE cluster's service account has the SQL Client role.

Comment: The error you are getting was not caused by any configuration of your setup but a Quota limitation on your `IN_USE_ADDRESSES`. You can simply fix that error by [requesting for increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).

Comment: Can you determine if without the quote restriction my approach with giving the private service connection address range to the Cluster default pod address range might be a way to make it work then?

Comment: Not sure about that, maybe you can fix the quota error first then proceed with further troubleshooting.